# Understanding the event and evidence parameters in bnlearns cpquery

Tags: r, bnlearn

I followed the [example](https://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/cpquery.html#:%7E:text=data(learning.test)%0Afitted%20%3D%20bn.fit(hc(learning.test)%2C%20learning.test)%0A%23%20the%20result%20should%20be%20around%200.025.%0Acpquery(fitted%2C%20(B%20%3D%3D%20%22b%22)%2C%20(A%20%3D%3D%20%22a%22))) for `cpquery(fitted, event, evidence, cluster, method = "ls", ..., debug = FALSE)` given in the documentation:

```r
#rm(list=ls())
library(bnlearn)

data(learning.test)
fitted = bn.fit(hc(learning.test), learning.test)
# the result should be around 0.025.
cpquery(fitted, (B == "b"), (A == "a"))
# out: 0.02692665
```

It worked as advertised, but I have some confusion about the syntax. For reference, `head(learning.test)` looks like this:

```
  A B C D E F
1 b c b a b b
2 b a c a b b
3 a a a a a a
4 a a a a b b
5 a a b c a a
6 c c a c c a
```

and the total number of rows is 5000.

Now to my confusion: The second argument to `cpquery`, `(B == "b")`, is passed to the `event` parameter and the third argument `(A == "a")` is passed to the `evidence` parameter. The documentation says about these two parameters that

> The `event` and `evidence` arguments must be two expressions describing the event of interest and the conditioning evidence in a format such that, if we denote with `data` the data set the network was learned from, `data[evidence, ]` and `data[event, ]` return the correct observations.

I didn't quite understand how the syntax `(B == "b")` worked, since I thought `B` is not defined in the current scope. So given what was said in the documentation above, I took `data` to be `learning.test` in my case and then I tried to do `learning.test[(B == "b"),]`, which indeed resulted in the error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(learning.test, (B == "b"), ) : 
  object 'B' not found
```

Given the documentation I thought this line of code should've worked.

I then tried to do `learning.test[(learning.test$B=="b"),]` which does seem to return a data frame with all rows where the `B`-column has the value `"b"`. I then tried to use this syntax in the `cpquery` function:

```r
cpquery(fitted, (learning.test$B == "b"), (learning.test$A == "a"))
```

but to my surprise this resulted in the error

```
Error in sampling(fitted = fitted, event = event, evidence = evidence,  : 
  logical vector for evidence is of length 5000 instead of 10000.
```

I don't understand why I get this error (other than that something goes wrong in the logical sampling used by `cpquery`), since as far as I can see I am conforming to the quoted passage from the documentation.

So in conclusion I wonder why does the example from the documentation work when it seems to **not conform** to the quoted passage from the documentation, and why does my modification not work even though it seems **to conform** to the quoted passage in the documentation? (I am not very familiary with R so maybe this is very basic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this section is just trying to show what the evidence and event expressions represent in the original data and how they relate to logic sampling. e.g. if you subset the original data with the event/evidence, then it will subset the data to only contains rows that agree with the event/evidence.

But you are correct that the notation `data[evidence, ]` won't work. You can use`learning.test[eval(expression(B == "b"), learning.test), ]`, which may help you understand the intent. This is similar to what used to appear in older help files.

For logic sampling (the default inference method) a bunch of samples are generated from the BN, the default is N=10000 samples (*). So 1) you have estimated a parameterised BN, 2) draw N samples from it, 3) subset this sample according to event / evidence vectors to calculate some conditional probability (hopefully correctness is not lost in my brevity).

`cpquery(fitted, (learning.test$B == "b"), (learning.test$A == "a"))` doesn't work as the default number of samples in the sampled BN (step 2. above) is 10000 but `learning.test` has 5000 rows (and so the logical vector produced by `(learning.test$B == "b")` has length 5000). You can force your approach to work, (by work I mean produce an answer), by setting the `n` parameter , `cpquery(fitted, (learning.test$B == "b"), (learning.test$A == "a"), n=5000)` but this will not always do what you expect: you are evaluating the event/evidence expression against the observed data instead of the simulated data. I think that if this sort of logical vector is supplied then `cpquery` should probably throw an error. Best to stick with the documented approaches.

(*) From the help I'd expect the default number of samples to be 5000 * log10(nparams(fitted))) =~ 8000, but perhaps `batch` = 10000 takes precedence.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! I would also like to add, since I just realized it, that the reason the example in the documentation does not throw an error complaining that `B` and `A` aren't defined is because R apparently uses some kind of lazy evaluation of function arguments. So it is possible to do `myfunc(undefinedObject)` as long as `myfunc` does not use `undefinedObject`. Just in case someone else not used to R would wonder about the same thing.